# Carousel from ng2-bootstrap is causing Angular Universal to get stuck in a loop

Tags: angular, carousel, ng2-bootstrap, angular-universal

I'm having a problem with ng2-bootsrap carousel. The page (/home2) loads fine when the carousel code in the page is commented out. But when the carousel code is running, the browser will keep waiting for the server to serve the page(which the server never will), causing the page to be empty. FYI, I'm using the Angular Universal Starter project.

Here is the carousel code with myInterval set to 5000 in the home2 component:

```
<carousel [interval]="myInterval" [noWrap]="noWrapSlides">
            <slide *ngFor="let slidez of slides;let index=index" [active]="slidez.active">
               <!-- <img [src]="slidez.image">-->
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h4>Slide {{index}}</h4>
                    <p>{{slidez.text}}</p>
                </div>
            </slide>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-left left carousel-control"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right right carousel-control"></i>
        </carousel>
```

Here is the output on the server side (express):

```
GET /home2 - - ms - -
inside ngApp
/home2
GET /home2 - - ms - -
nginside ngApp
/home2
GET /home2 - - ms - -
inside ngApp
/home2
GET /home2 - - ms - -
```

Here is the console log statements on the server:

```
function ngApp(req, res) {
  console.log("inside ngApp");
  console.log(req.originalUrl);
  res.render('index', {
    req,
    res,
    // time: true, // use this to determine what part of your app is slow only in development
    preboot: false,
    baseUrl: '/',
    requestUrl: req.originalUrl,
    originUrl: `http://localhost:${ app.get('port') }`
  });
}
```

It appears to me Angular Universal is stuck in a loop. 
Here is the implementation: [interior design ideas](http://rinteriordesign.com) with the interval disabled in order to avoid the infinite loop. I would appreciate it if anyone could tell me how to fix this. 
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hey.. if you got the answer please update here. I also got stuck in this issue. thankx

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem but found solution , ng2-bootstrap use browser element and need wait until app bootstrap in client you must create own carousel compatible with universal or with ***ngIf** wait until bootstrap you must in component check with below code :

```
import {isBrowser} from "angular2-universal";

if (isBrowser) {
  //example 
    this.showCarousel = true;
}
```